# Is it possible to rewrite on Camera Roll photos?

Tags: swift

I wonder is it possible in iOS 8 to rewrite on Camera Roll pictures after applying some changes? If yes is there any sample code which rewrite pictures?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, you are not allowed to rewrite the camera roll (or really an internal data) on an iOS device in either Swift or Objective-C. This is to eliminate apps on the app store that are detrimental to user experience or harmful to the iOS system.

However, in iOS 8, you can use an extension in the photos app to edit photos directly (if you have custom filters or something). This is native to the photos app, not your app.

This is a great article on how to do just that: 
http://www.appcoda.com/photo-editing-extensions/

Hope that helped!